# How to use Func("variable") in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, com

I'm using COM interface to get functions from 3rd party application. There's a findElement function which has a usage of this type Object.findElement("String Value"). So how can I put my variable Body in this function? Because if I put " symbol before and after from my variable it doesn't recognize my variable it uses Body as string value. If i don't put these icons it gives an error from 3rd part application.

```
Set Body = Bodies.Item(i)

Worksheets("Test").Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = Mdl.findElement("Body").m.src
```

Could you please help me to solve this problem.

Regards.

Comment: (a) You cannot use an `object` as a parameter to a function that is expecting a `String` (unless the object has a default property of some sort, and that default property can be coerced to a string) (b) Without knowing what your `Bodies` object is, what your `Body` object is, what the `Mdl` object is, what the `findElement` method is meant to do, and what the parameter to the `findElement` method is meant to represent, there is probably not much help we can give.

Comment: findElement is looking for `string` type parameter. Bodies.item(i) is not of type `string`. Quickest way is to `Cstr(Body)`. Not robust but may work.